# Call specific function if one exists, otherwise the default from the protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following situation: there's a protocol version of a function and there might be a specific one of structs that implement that protocol. If a specific one exists, I want to call that one, otherwise the default one.

This works if the type is most specific. But if I'm somewhere (like iterating over a collection) where just the protocol conformance is granted, what's the best way to check if a specific function exists?

In the following I'm checking in the generic implementation if the instance is more special. But that's somewhat manual as I have to know myself which of the structs (..Agents) implements the function.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
import Cocoa

protocol Agent {
    func doSomething()
}
extension Agent {
    func doSomething() {
        if let specialAgent = self as? SpecialAgent {
            specialAgent.doSomething()
            return
        } // same for fooAgent, barAgent, ...
        print("extension implementation")
    }
}

struct SpecialAgent: Agent {
    func doSomething() {
        print("specific implementation")
    }
}

// this would be somewhere where we get all kinds of Agents and act on them
let agents: [Agent] = [SpecialAgent()]
for agent in agents {
    agent.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Why isn't doSomething() part of the protocol so that each struct conforming to Agent has their own implementation of it? It seems what you are trying to do anyway now

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the transfer

Comment: What's the issue here?  Your code should already do what you want it to as long as you have the function declared as a protocol requirement like you added in your edit